# Leaflet: markers icon does not show up in heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, leaflet

I use leaflet to show a map with some markers in my Rails 4 application.
In development environement, everything is ok. But when I deploy on heroku, the map is displayed but not the markers.
When I checked the errors in the browser, I've noticed the following:

```
Error: Couldn't autodetect L.Icon.Default.imagePath, set it manually.
```

What I understand is that the framework could not locate the icon image. So I downloaded the last version of leaflet from their site and moved files to vendor/assets/javascripts/leaflet and vendor/assets/stylesheets/leaflet and vendor/assets/images/leaflet.
I have **config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false** in my configuration file:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I run:

```
$> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=staging
```

Then I deploy to my staging environment hosted by heroku.
Do you have any idea? Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can also just set it manually:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = 'path-to-your-leaflet-images-folder';
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating leaflet from 0.6.2 to 0.6.4 solved the problem.

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'leaflet-rails', '>=0.6.4'
...
```

Comment: How about for manually including the leaflet src files without using the gem? I'm experiencing the same error and it's because the precompile messes up the path.

Comment: I'm having same issue with assets precompile - Without using Gem. any solution ?